# Can't pickle SARIMAX

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, arima

Error when trying to pickle arima model within statsmodels.api

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(...)
results = mod.fit()
results.save("test.pkl")
```

Returns Error:

TypeError: can't pickle statsmodels.tsa.statespace._statespace.dStatespace objects